# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error on Windows for https://downdetector.ru/

Tags: python, web-scraping, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to run a simple web-scraping code in cmd Windows10:

```
import requests
url = 'https://downdetector.ru/ne-rabotaet/tinkoff-bank/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0', 'Referrer': 'downdetector.ru'}
response = requests.get(url, 'html.parser', headers=headers)
print(response)
```

and getting an error:

```
SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))
```

The weirdest thing is that when my colleague runs this exact code on his MacOS, it works perfectly fine. So what could be the problem here?

P.S. I've read all the other questions considering this topic and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused of not having the certificate used in https://downdetector.ru in your computer.

Your code can work if you set verify parameter False as follows. Know that this is not suggested.

```
response = requests.get(url, 'html.parser', headers=headers, verify=False)
```

You can find here more detail about verify parameter. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

`Note that when verify is set to False, requests will accept any TLS certificate presented by the server, and will ignore hostname mismatches and/or expired certificates, which will make your application vulnerable to man-in-the-middle (MitM) attacks. Setting verify to False may be useful during local development or testing.`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've read the documentation, but I'd prefer not to use anything that is unsafe and rather find out the reason why it works on MacOS and doesn't work on Windows.